# Unable to add a record in Aerospike Cache using Spring Cacheable

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, caching, aerospike

I am implementing A Cache in DAO layer using Spring Cache by using annotation @Cacheable. This is my following Code .

```
    @Override
@Cacheable(value="saleSegmentCache3")
public List<SaleSegment> findBySuborder(String pincode,long subcatID) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    System.out.println("String is printing");
    return ssRepo.findSaleSegmentsByPincodeAndSubcategoryIdAndSegmentType(pincode,subcatID, SaleSegmentType.SUBCAT_PINCODE);
}
```

Over here i am able to retreive the data , but i am not being able to put the data into Cache. I am using one more example  :

```
    @Override
@Cacheable(value="saleSegmentCache3" ,key="#soData")
public String findBySuborderTemp(String soData) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    System.out.println("String XYZZZZZZZ");
    return "MyString";

}
```

Here i am able to Cache the String Perfectly and able to store the data in the cache .
I think Something is wrong with the syntax that i have used

Answer (score 1):

`spring-data-aerospike` is still in unfinished state. We are planning to move it to the separate project `aerospike-spring-cache` and implement missing functionality.

Answer (score 0):

There were some big changes in the Cache area in Spring Data Aerospike - starting from versions 2.5.0/3.0.0.

You can see an example of using @Cacheable and much more in this medium article:
https://medium.com/aerospike-developer-blog/caching-with-spring-boot-and-aerospike-17b91267d6c

Answer (score 0):

Try like below and see if it works:

```
    @Cacheable(value = "test", key = "#id")
public Optional<User> getUserById(int id) {
    log.info("Reading User Details with ID: {}", id);
    return userRepository.findById(id);
}

@CachePut(value = "test", key = "#user.id")
public User addUser(User user) {
    log.info("Adding User Details with Name: {}", user.getName());
    return userRepository.save(user);
}

@CacheEvict(value = "test", key = "#id")
public boolean removeUserById(int id) {
    log.info("Removing User Details with ID: {}", id);
    userRepository.deleteById(id);
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).